# how to match an image with the image taken from camera? android

Tags: java, android, image, image-processing, android-camera

Hi in my application I have a printed color palette. I have a camera application built from the android sdk. My goal is to detect individual color from the palette when the color palette is captured by the phone. How can I achieve that? for example my color palette is like this, 
[image: color palette]

My goal is to detect all 15 colors or at-least the middle points of the squares in the camera application.